# How to get sum of each column from the same select query

Tags: oracle10g, subtotal

I have a table as follows

```
    Col1    Col2    Col3    Col4
    ------------------------------
    100     400     400     300
    200     600     400     700
    800     600     500     900
    300     100     700     500
   --------------------------------
    Total   1700    2000    2400
```

IAs you can see, I want total of each column (excluding 1st column). 
I am not sure whether we can fetch the total of each column with same select query which I am using to fetch this data.

If not please suggest any alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Use `UNION ALL` operator to get this done like,

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4 
FROM   <table>
UNION ALL
SELECT NULL, sum(col2), sum(col3), sum(col4)
FROM   <table>;
```

Answer (score 0):

Why cant you achieve this by simple select statement,

```
select sum(col2),sum(col3),sum(col4) from table;
```

Hope this works !!